# Create Character Variable that Includes List of Numbers for a Search Function

Tags: r, string, escaping, concatenation, character

Can anyone help me with a character syntax issue? I have a dataframe column with a list of numbers (as characters):

```
df$issn
   [1] "2369-2960" "1532-2777" "1876-2026" "1872-7727" "1872-7123"
   [6] "1532-2777" "1542-7714" "1879-1190" "1090-2139" "1090-2139"
```

I need to convert them a specific syntax for them to work in a function from the RISmed package. I don't think you need to worry about the details of the package. If I can just get the search into the right format everything should work.

Here's output with me manually inserting the numbers in the correct format:

```
>  EUtilsSummary('2369-2960 OR 1532-2777 OR 1876-2026 OR 1872-7727',
+     retmax=100, mindate= 2018, maxdate= 2021, datetype = "edat")
[1] "\"JMIR Public Health Surveill\"[Journal] OR \"Med Hypotheses\"[Journal] OR \"Asian J Psychiatr\"[Journal] OR \"Eur J Radiol\"[Journal] AND 2018[EDAT] : 2021[EDAT]"
>
```

So you can see that I need the search to be 'number OR number OR number'.  I wrote a paste function to make that happen, which it looks like is working fine:

```
> issns <- paste0("\'", paste0(unique(df$issn), collapse = " OR "), "\'")
> issns
[1] "'2369-2960 OR 1532-2777 OR 1876-2026 OR 1872-7727 OR 1872-7123 OR 1542-7714 OR 1879-1190 OR 1090-2139 OR 1873-6513...
```

It's like 800 of these numbers so I cut it off there. Anyway, when I run my function WITH the issns variable, I get an error:

```
> EUtilsSummary(issns,
+     retmax=100,  mindate= 2018, maxdate= 2021, datetype = "edat") 
Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term='2369-2960+OR+1532-2777+OR+1876-2026+OR+1872-7727+OR+1872-7123+OR+1542-7714+OR+1879-1190+OR+1090-2139+OR+1873-6513+OR+1523-6838+OR+1532-2742+OR+1474-4457+OR+1555
```

Why is this happening? Theoretically:

1. Inserting my issns variable should be the same as just typing them out, right?
2. Is there some syntax / coding function I'm missing? Have tried a bunch of things with no benefit.

Comment: Have you tried `issns <- paste0(unique(df$issn), collapse = " OR ")`, i.e. leaving out `'`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who reached out! Figured I would answer this to avoid anyone wasting time on it.

Turns out somewhere upstream (RISmed? Pubmed?) internally clocks how many of these ISSNs I can possibly put into the search parameters.  I ran a bunch of more limited sets through and once I go a ways over 500 ISSN numbers it shuts you down.

So I just broke the search into chunks then ran an RBIND to combine the DFs. Inelegant but functional. Thanks!